# VBA PivotField.VisibleItems.count is always equal to 1 and contains "(All)"

Tags: excel, vba

I Find the following code on the Microsoft web site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.visibleitems, with this comment :
"This example adds the names of all visible items in the field named Product to a list on a new worksheet."

```
    Set nwSheet = Worksheets.Add 
    nwSheet.Activate 
    Set pvtTable = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PivotTable 
    rw = 0 
    For Each pvtItem In pvtTable.PivotFields("Product").VisibleItems 
       rw = rw + 1 
       nwSheet.Cells(rw, 1).Value = pvtItem.Name 
    Next
```

In my case, despite the fact that I have set several filters values on that PivotField, "by hand", using the mouse, VisibleItems.count is always equal to 1, and VisibleItems(1)="(All)"

Who can help ??

I expect some advices : may be some settings on the PivotTable, PivotField ...

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your pivot table? I'm unable to reproduce.

Comment: Long time ago, it happened to me. It seems with my Excel 2010 version, the .visibleitems won't work if the field is in the Report Filter. It will work if the field is in Row Labels. Since your result .viaibleitems.count always 1, so I assume that your page field is in Report Filter. To test, move your page field to Row Labels, select a few items. Then it should give a correct result for the `pvtTable.PivotFields("Product").VisibleItems.count`. If the pf in Report Filter, I think you need to check `For Each pvtItem In pvtTable.PivotFields("Product").pivotitems: if pvtItem.visible=true then..`

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Actually if the field is as "filter", VisibleItems is set to 1. But if one moves the field as "RowField", then VisibleItems is updated !! So I moved the field to "RowFields", then I get the VisibleItems list, and just after I move back the field as "xlPageField" ... And it works